# Como concatenar um objeto javascript à um formulario post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

Eu tenho um objeto `JSON` que construí em tempo de execução, preciso que ele seja enviado para meu `servlet`, junto com os demais campos do formulário, via post, como faço isso? Pesquisei bastante mas nada funcionou.

```
function createJSON() {

    layoutColunas = [];
    $(".colSubWrapper").each(function() {

        var item = {};

        var nomeColuna = $(this).find(".colJSON").eq(0).val();
        item ["nome_coluna"] = nomeColuna;

        var tipoColuna = $(this).find(".colJSON").eq(1).val();
        item ["tipo_coluna"] = tipoColuna;

        layoutColunas.push(item);

    });

    return layoutColunas;
}
$("#formBaseCadastrar").on("submit", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("tentou fazer submit");
    var layoutColunas = createJSON();
    $('.colJSON').prop('disabled', true);
    var data = $("#formBaseCadastrar").serialize();
    data = data + '&' + $.param(layoutColunas);
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/QualidadeWeb/basesCadastrar",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#pageContainer").load("/QualidadeWeb/resultado?resp="+encodeURIComponent(data));
        },  
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log("deu errado");
        }
    });
});
```

Por mais que meu objeto funcione normalmente, essa função `$.param(layoutColunas);` cria um paramentro `undefined`. Ao usar f12 para tracking do Protocolo Post, o resultado foi o seguinte:

```
nomeBase=base1234&conexao=234234&telefone=324234&tipoBase=4&undefined=&undefined=
```

Meu objeto é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: o que `console.log(layoutColunas)` imprime se você colocar logo antes de `return layoutColunas;`?

Comment: @mercador ele imprime o exato mesmo objeto JSON que o return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação da função [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

> If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Traduzindo

> se objeto passado está em um *array*, ele deve ser um *array* de objetos no formato retornado por [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Exemplo do formato necessário:

```
[
  { name: "first", value: "Rick" },
  { name: "last", value: "Astley" },
  { name: "job", value: "Rock Star" }
]
```

`jQuery.param()` constrói o parâmetro *string* usando as chaves `name` e `value` de cada objeto no *array*. Os seus objetos apenas possuem chaves `nome_coluna` e `tipo_coluna`, portanto eles não são serializados corretamente.

Comment: Legal, vou testar aqui!!!

Comment: nomeBase=Base1234&conexao=1234&telefone=34234&tipoBase=1&nome_cliente=1&cpf=2. Funcionou, muito obrigado!